# OptionMenu in Tkinter TopLevel not working properly

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So, basically i have this code:

```
class Top(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.num = 10
        self.items = range(6)
        self.pack()
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        menu = Toplevel()
        frame = Frame(menu,padx=5,pady=5)

        variables = []
        menus = []
        callbacks = []

        def assign():
            pass

        for i in range(self.num):
            Label(frame,text=str(i)).grid(sticky='W',row = i,column=0)
            variables.append(StringVar(""))
            menus.append(OptionMenu(frame,variables[i],""))
            callbacks.append(assign)
            menus[i].configure(width=10)
            menus[i].grid(sticky='W',row = i,column=1)
            for item in self.items:
                menus[i]["menu"].add_command(label=str(item),command=callbacks[i])
                variables[i].set(str(i*i))
        frame.grid()
        menu.grid()

root = Tk()
top = Top(root)
top.mainloop()
```

Now, when I click on one of the entries, it does not change to this specific entry. What am I overlooking? It is structured like that because the number of the entries and the corresponding items in the OptionMenus AND the callbacks are dynamically changing with each call. Also, if the entry actually changes, what is the best way to get the current entry?

Regards,Kai

Comment: "When I click on an entry it does not change to this entry" doesn't make much sense. Also, your optionmenus are calling the callback, but your callback doesn't do anything.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation please? Also, you don't need all of those backslashes at the ends of lines that are continued.

Comment: I edited the code for your convenience. The callback does not do anything because at this point, it is non essential, I simply left out the code. Ok, let me clarify my problem. When you click at the OptionMenu, it drops down and you see the options. When you click on one of these options, the first field changes to this option and you have "selected" it. Usually. But with this implementation nothing happens. Am I making sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using `OptionMenu` correctly. You are removing all of its built-in behavior. The proper way to create an `OptionMenu` is to give it all of the items at the time you create the widget. Internally, the `OptionMenu` will use the `command` attribute of each menu item to manage the value. By creating your own menu items with their own commands, you are preventing the widget from working properly.

There's nothing wrong with creating your own menubutton with a menu (which is all that the OptionMenu is...), but if you do so then you'll have to take care of the detail of making sure the menubutton label matches the value. If you want the automatic behavior, you need to use the `OptionMenu` as it was intended to be used.

A decent tutorial can be found here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/optionmenu.htm

Comment: You are right. It is a subtle yet important distinction. Thank you!